# Can I modify an ENUM with a query from php?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a query that I can use to change the value of an ENUM from php without having to go directly to the database?

My aim is to create a button that gives the user the ability to modify an ENUM without having to go to the database every time they need to add to or change it.

Comment: use alter query and execute in php whenever u want to get change

Comment: By the way, if possible values of field are variable (may change as a result of using application), it doesn't make sense to make it enum at all. It should be separate table with possible values.

Comment: @dragoste you are right but for me it's already difficult to make and drag and drop so I found a guide to do it.. My target is to make an horizontal drag and drop in a table and save always the position of the object moved

Comment: @Kool-Mind thanks, that's what I was already thinking

Comment: welcome buddy it's good to help

Comment: Hi there - I improved the wording a bit and made the title of the question crystal clear so that people seeing it on the front page will know exactly what it is you're after.

Answer (score -3):

You can do with this:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname INTEGER;
```

Comment: INTEGER and ENUM are not the same field type.